# var Array of objects not initialising

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, nullpointerexception

I've a following code :-

```
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String,  entrygpsdt: String,lastgpsdt: String)

object recalculate extends Serializable {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("db", "table").select("imei", "date", "gpsdt").where("imei=? and date=? and gpsdt>? and gpsdt<?", entry(0), entry(1), entry(2), entry(3))
    var lastgpsdt = "2018-04-06 10:10:10"
    var updatedValues = new Array[event](rdd.count().toInt)
    var index = 0

    rdd.foreach(f => {
      val imei = f.get[String]("imei")
      val date = f.get[String]("date")
      val gpsdt = f.get[String]("gpsdt")
      updatedValues(index) = new event(imei, date, gpsdt,lastgpsdt)
      println(updatedValues(index).toString())
      index = index + 1
      lastgpsdt = gpsdt
    })
    println("updates values are " + updatedValues.toString())
}}
```

So, here I'm trying to create an array of event class answer save values in array on each iteration and want to access the array outside foreach block. My issue is when I'm trying to access the array it gives null pointer exception and i checked it shows the array is empty. Although I have declared the array as var still why not able to access outside. Suggestions please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `Array[event]` then I don't think that is the right approach

Here is what you can do for alternative

```
case class event(imei: String, date: String, gpsdt: String,
                 entrygpsdt: String,lastgpsdt: String)

val result = rdd.map(row => {
  val imei = row.getString(0)
  val date = row.getString(1)
  val gpsdt = row.getString(2)
  //create case class as you want 
  event(imei, date, gpsdt, lastgpsdt ,"2018-04-06 10:10:10")
})
.collect()
```

The result you obtain is `Array[event]`

`Collect` is also preferred only when your data size is small and can fit in a driver.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, Shankar, how will I return event when I have to store values like gpsdt after this event initialisation.  lastgpsdt = gpsdt So , idea is that I'm storing gpsdt on each iteration and this will become lastgpdst for next row . So i, think If i return the value I'll not be able to save

Comment: How can you know you are getting the previous value is it sorted. rdd.foreach works on each executer. You can use lag function from dataframe to get the previous value of any column, if it is sorted.

Comment: my RDD is sorted I'm using val rsscopy = rss.sortBy(row => row.get[String]("gpsdt"), false) which gives an sorted result so for each iteration, take it as it is sorted always

Comment: You already got the dataframe just use lag fucntion to get the previous row value and convert to array of events as above

Comment: amazing it worked . Thanks a ton @Shankar for helping me out. Thank you for your precious time :) . I'm accepting your answer

Comment: Sure, glad that helped you :)